Django Framework CSRF verification failed with 403 Forbidden error. Request aborted for non-HTML python script
I am using Django Framework with DRF to generate APIs at the backend. I am using python script as an standalone windows based application to retrieve and send data to the backend server which is Django. It is not HTML application and no Cookies are involved. It is simply running python script with "request" library. I am also using JWT authentication token to secure my requests to server. While making request to fetch the token to the server I am getting below error:
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.
Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set.
My Settings.py is as below:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'autobiz.middleware.WebSocketMiddleware',
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",

REST_FRAMEWORK={
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend', ],
#    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[ 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication','rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication','rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':['rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser', 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',],
}


My urls.py is as below:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('abpublic.urls'), name='index'),
    path('api/token/', csrf_exempt(jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view()), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', csrf_exempt(jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view()), name='token_refresh'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


My views.py is as below:
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filterset_fields = ['empid', 'password', 'type', 'reporting_to', 'role', 'active', 'last_login_date',
                        'last_created_date',
                        'last_login_time', 'last_created_time', 'joindate', 'leavedate', ]


Now in python script, I am first trying to retrieve token and then provide as a header to the query. But, while generating token I am facing the issue.
 # Request the token
                token_response = requests.post(tenant + "api/token/", data=credentials)

                # Check if the request was successful
                if token_response.status_code == 200:
                    tokens = token_response.json()
                    access_token = tokens.get('access')  # The access token
                    print(access_token)
                    refresh_token = tokens.get('refresh')  # The refresh token
                else:
                    print('Failed to obtain token:', token_response.status_code, token_response.text)
                    access_token = None

                # Token has changed, split the token into its components
                token_parts = token.split('#')
                if len(token_parts) != 6:
                    print("Invalid token format")
                    continue


I have tried searching and applied some solutions as below:
    path('api/token/', csrf_exempt(jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view()), name='token_obtain_pair'),


Also tried adding,
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True


But no solution is working. As it is not HTML application, I wonder how to secure my queries.

Non-browser requests don't consume nor send cookies, nor is CSRF used by JWT authentication schemes. So this is a little weird. A part of the clue is probably given - the error suggests that forms are being used somewhere, which is an indicator that there's some element to this that you've omitted from the code. Please share the full traceback (from the server console) when the error occurs.

At server console I am getting only below output:
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/token/
[27/Sep/2024 07:03:13] "POST /api/token/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2855

need template.html

@django.seolpyo.com not understood. Do you mean I should add template.html (Dummy) for the sake of execution? My client is non-HTML.
